# Rails - Filter Chain has Halted as <method> rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im intrigued by this message that is currently showing up on my api logs (Rails 6)

`Filter chain halted as :response_in_cache rendered or redirected`

controller:

```
  before_action :response_in_cache, only: [:index]

  def index
    items = resource(User, query_params)
    RequestCachingService.set_response_cache(request.fullpath, items.to_json)
    json_response(items)
  end
```

application_controller (where the before_action method is defined)

```
    def response_in_cache
      if RequestCachingService.response_in_cache(request.fullpath) != false
        json_response(JSON.parse(RequestCachingService.response_in_cache(request.fullpath)))
      end
    end
```

json_response method:

```
  def json_response(object, status = :ok)
    render json: object, status: status
  end
```

`response_in_cache` does indeed calls render, if validation passes. is this bad practice?

Everything works as expected by the way, I just noticed this on my logs, and am not sure if it is a bad problem smell, even though the code works at the end of the day.

Would be grateful for any tips on how to fix or improve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: While I'm not sure what the best way to change it would be, I do find it a little twisty. I understand the intent, but wonder if it'd make more sense to build this in a way that either uses an existing caching gem (whatever it's called now) or doesn't remove the rendering from the action.

Comment: The  `RequestCachingService.response_in_cache(request.fullpath)` can also not call render or redirect, it seems that is the issue. I feel this is a strange implementation overall.

Comment: I think it is a bad practice. Any other callback like authentication may be skipped due to this. I would call `response_in_cache` explicitly in index action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly fine. It is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. `before_action` does not let the main action execute if you `render or redirect` anything from it(directly or based on some conditions). This is expected.

Comment: I changed this and got rid of the log error